# How can I add dropdown menu

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, menu, toplinks

[image]

The above image is of top-links. I wanted to add a drop-down for My Account. When the user click or hover on it, My Account should show My account option For example orders.

Answer (score 2):

Create phtml template file

```
<div class="customer-menu">
 <span class="action toggle"  data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}' data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
     <span class="title"><?= __("Customer Menu"); ?></span>
 </span>
 <ul class="dropdown">
     <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Call block out in XML where you want

```
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header-dropdown" template="Custom_Module::header-dropdown.phtml"/>
```

Add design into less file

```
.customer-menu {
    .lib-dropdown();
}
```

Move your links into dropdown with xml (example: my account link)

```
 <move element="my-account-link" destination="header-dropdown" />
```

Comment: This Works very well but there is a problem. The page should be completely loaded otherwise it give an error a javascript error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined

Comment: Could you give more info about that error? I'm working on Blank theme and can't get that error.

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a static block with the links in it that you want in them. Echo the static block using a .phtml or .xml file while assigning a class to it. Style the block to your wishes and set it to `display: none` in your CSS. Then, when a user hovers over your link, set it to `display: block` using Javascript (or use `.show()` in combination with jQuery).

Hopefully this may get you on the right tracks. The pro of using a static block is that you can easily edit the content in the drop down menu via the admin panel.

Comment: Can't we do it using magento way?